# Traveling in December (Italy and Switzerland) - By Car

Tags: driving, car-rentals, weather-and-climate

Everyone!

I'm planning a trip from Milan with a rental car **in December** (11), to Germany (Munich), via Austria.

From Munich, I go to Liechtenstein, then to Switzerland, arriving in the city of  **Lauterbrunnen**.

Finally, I will go to Zurich and return to Milan.

My question is regarding the weather conditions during this period of the year, especially in the city of Liechtenstein. Using highways, **are bad driving conditions to be expected?**

Since I'm using a rental car, do they come with snow tires? How is this issue?

I'm looking for a lot of information, but I'm not finding many details about this route, specifically at this time of year.

Can anyone provide me with tips and details of the route?

> Ps.: The car will be a kia RIO (or similar)

Hugs,

Comment: There is no city of Liechtenstein; it is a country comprising 11 municipalities, none of which shares the name.  My impression is that you'll be fine unless it's snowing during your drive or has snowed shortly before it, assuming you plan to stay on the major roads.  Communities are well supplied with snow clearing equipment.  Road closures do happen in the Alps during storms, though, so be prepared to be flexible.  I don't have experience driving in that part of Switzerland in the winter, though, so I am not particularly qualified to post an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up writing Liechtenstein as a city, but, in fact, I was referring to the country itself, I apologize!

Comment: I think you took out the wrong "the city of": while Lauterbrunnen is also not a city, it is at least a municipality.

Comment: Is there a reason you backtrack to Zurich after Lauterbrunnen? It’s very close to the route from Liechtenstein to Lauterbrunnen. Unless you make a detour via Bern for instance. Also is there a reason to use a car for all this rather than enjoy scenic train rides?

Comment: If you're worried about weather condition, why not take the train instead?

Answer (score 4):

It is difficult to predict the weather, but you are not going up to mountains, so I think you should not have problems (but to traverse the Alps). Also main route should be cleared quickly.
If there is a snowstorm (and you get it in the news early), plan a longer travel time.

So the only problem is to travel to Milan. Seldom the highway is blocked when there are huge storms (trucks/lorries slide and block the route, so the route cannot be keep clean (and also cars are quickly blocked by snow). Noting dangerous, but annoying (and not so frequent: one day every few years).

The car should be equipped with winter tire, and probably the necessary to clean it up from snow, but if there is a snowstorm, try to park in a covered parking.

Route: check GPS and Google maps: actual traffic data is much better then our predictions.

Note: If you want to reduce risk, maybe you should go first to Liechtenstein, then Zurich, and only later Lauterbrunnen. Near Lauterbrunnen you (and your car) can take the train to pass the Alps: a lot of people do it to reach the canton of Wallis/Valais), you can have a transportation to Loetschberg and Simplon (see https://www.bls.ch/en/fahren/autoverlad check Kandersteg (near Lauterbrunnen), and Iselle (in Italy). Or if you are flexible, just look weather forecast on site, and decide for the best way.

Comment: Thank you a lot! A sent an email to the rental company (ecoviarent) asking about the winter tire. I think it is possible.

I'm going to adopt your route suggestion, because, it makes more sense, in Zurich (or nearby), I can check the conditions of Lauterbrunnen, and then decide to go or not

Thank you!!